# AES CBC PKCS Algorithm in Windows Phone 8

Tags: encryption, windows-phone-8, aes

I am developing an application in Android, windows 8 Tablet/Desktop and Windows phone 8.I am using AES CBC algorithm in Android and Windows 8 Tablet/Desktop application and able to encrypt and decrypt properly.I have to use the same algorithm in Windows phone 8.I tried it from an example available from web but the problem is when a same string is encrypted in Windows 8 Tab/Desktop application and Windows phone 8 both are different.I am sure that Windows Tab/Desktop is working fine as it is already in the appstore and it works fine with Android application.

Android code of the algorithm

public static String encrypt(String plainText, String password) throws Exception {

```
    if (plainText == null || plainText.length() == 0)
        return "";

    // convert key to bytes
    byte[] keyBytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    // Use the first 16 bytes (or even less if key is shorter)

    byte[] keyBytes16 = new byte[16];

    System.arraycopy(keyBytes, 0, keyBytes16, 0,
            Math.min(keyBytes.length, 16));

    // convert plain text to bytes
    byte[] plainBytes = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");

    // setup cipher
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes16, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] iv = new byte[16]; // initialization vector with all 0
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

    // encrypt
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
    String encryptedString = Base64.encodeToString(
            cipher.doFinal(plainBytes), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    // encryptedString

    return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

Windows Phone 8

```
public static string Encrypt1(string dataToEncrypt, string password, string salt)


 {

AesManaged aes = null;
            MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = null;


try
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[16];
                byte[] pwd = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
                byte[] pwd1 = new byte[16];
                for (int i = 0; i < 16;i++ ) // take first 16 bits of the password
                {
                    pwd1[i] = pwd[i];
                }

String newPwd = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pwd1, 0 ,pwd1.Length);

                //Generate a Key based on a Password, Salt and HMACSHA1 pseudo-random number generator 
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(newPwd, b);

                //Create AES algorithm with 256 bit key and 128-bit block size 
                aes = new AesManaged();
                //aes.BlockSize = aes.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;
                aes.KeySize = 128;
                aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(128 / 8);
                aes.IV = rfc2898.GetBytes(128 / 8);
                //aes.IV = b;
                //Create Memory and Crypto Streams 
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                //Encrypt Data 
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToEncrypt);
                cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                //Return Base 64 String 
                return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cryptoStream != null)
                    cryptoStream.Close();
                if (memoryStream != null)
                    memoryStream.Close();
                if (aes != null)
                    aes.Clear();
            }
        }
```

I know there is something wrong in my win phone 8 algo. Please help me out to find it out.Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So are you using the same code in Windows and in Windows phone 8? I don't see how this could go wrong with the same code base. Normally the encoding could be an issue. Note that for a secure encryption routine *you would use a unique/random IV* so you would also *expect* each encryption to be different. You are currently leaking data.

Answer (score 0):

You are using PBKDF2 key derivation scheme `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` in the Windows application and a directly created key / IV in the android code. Please upgrade the Android code to use PBKDF2 (look at this site for implementations) and - if you are going to send the ciphertext over a network - don't forget to add an authentication tag to protect against man-in-the-middle and padding oracle attacks.

Note that just copying the code from the internet is not going to give you much of protection against attackers. You need to understand what you are protecting against and at least some basics of applied cryptography before you start to implement anything.

**When** you start to implement cryptography then note that it is not very forgiving regarding small errors. A single wrong bit will completely mess up your ciphertext - no warnings, no specific errors. So log all the hexadecimal representation of *all* your input/output parameters - this would have shown you a different key and IV for value early.

Comment: And don't forget to remove or disable the logging in the final version of course, showing the key in plain is probably not going to humor any user.

Comment: Owlstead,appreciate your prompt reply.The Android app is already in market, so are iOS and windows 8 tab/desktop apps.I made it to work in all these platforms.Cant I change the code in windows phone 8 to make it compatible with other platforms.

Comment: That's a shame, because there are quite a few security related problems in above code - static salts, static IV, incorrect key derivation, no authentication tag...